# ADB, but not by Eclipse, finds my Android device via USB

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, adb, device

It worked until today when after starting Eclipse my hardware, a Samsung S3, does not turn up as an option for "run configuration" in Eclipse for Windows 7. But it's serial number string is listed when I run "adb devices" in the command prompt.

Is there some way to force a connection between ADB and Eclipse? Any other kind of solution?

I have restarted and even updated the SDK.

Last things I did in Eclipse befor the problem were importing a github project and updating android support library. Seems completely unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Eclispe ->

Connect your Device ->

open DDMS perspective ->

From DDMS Reset ADB ->
your Device will show up , no need to restart Eclipse

Comment: Yes! The device still doesn't show up in the "run configuration" dialog, but when I just "run" then it's there and it works. Eclipse confusion. Thanks!